# Query to compute unspecified values in "Other" category

Tags: mysql, mariadb

The problem that we are trying to solve is explained herein using a simple (and deliberately sub-normalized) table.

Sample schema and data

```
create table expense_profile
(
  id  INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name  VARCHAR(10),
  category  VARCHAR(16),
  percentage DECIMAL(15,2),
  
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);  

INSERT INTO expense_profile(name, category, percentage)
VALUES('Alice', 'Housing', 15), ('Alice', 'Transportation', 5),
('Alice', 'Food', 25), ('Alice', 'Utilities', 5),
('Alice', 'Healthcare', 5), ('Alice', 'Personal', 3),
('Bob', 'Transportation', 7), ('Bob', 'Food', 18),
('Bob', 'Healthcare', 8), ('Bob', 'Personal', 20);
```

In this table we have accounted for 58% of Alice's expenses and 53% of Bob's expenses.  Implied therein is that 42% of Alice's expenses and 47% of Bob's expenses are in the **"Other"** category.

---

**Q)** Is there a query that would allow us to list, for the specified user, all the categories, including the "Other" category?

---

For example, we would like to have the following output for Bob:

```
+------+----------------+------------+
| name | category       | percentage |
+------+----------------+------------+
| Bob  | Transportation |       7.00 |
| Bob  | Food           |      18.00 |
| Bob  | Healthcare     |       8.00 |
| Bob  | Personal       |      20.00 |
| Bob  | Other          |      47.00 |
+------+----------------+------------+
```

Comment: This looks like an assignment question. Please post your efforts so we can help where you are stuck in the query. One solution involves a basic SELECT with a `UNION`.

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
(SELECT name, category, percentage FROM expense_profile GROUP BY name , category ) 
 union 
(SELECT name,'Other',100-sum(percentage) AS percentage FROM expense_profile GROUP BY name HAVING percentage>0) 
ORDER BY name, category='Other',category;
```